# Jquery multiple selectors with this

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I've searched but can't find how to do this.  I'm trying to make the elements with `comment-modbox` inside `this` hide and show:

```
$('.comment-wrapper').each(function (index) {

    $(this, '.comment-modbox').mouseover(function () {
        $('.comment-modbox').show();
    });

    $(this, '.comment-modbox').mouseout(function () {
        $('.comment-modbox').hide();
    });
});
```

This code just hides and shows all `comment-modbox` regardless as to if they are contained within `this`.

Thanks for any help!

### Answer:

```
$('.comment-wrapper').each(function (index) {

    $(this).mouseover(function () {
        $('.comment-modbox', this).show();
    });

    $(this).mouseout(function () {
        $('.comment-modbox', this).hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this ([jQuery("selector", context)...](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/))

```
$('.comment-wrapper').each(function (index) {

    $('.comment-modbox', this).mouseover(function () {
        $(this).show();
    });

    $('.comment-modbox', this).mouseout(function () {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

Second choice:

```
$('.comment-wrapper').each(function (index) {

    var wrapper = this; 

    $('.comment-modbox', wrapper)
        .mouseover(function () {
            $(this).show();
        })
        .mouseout(function () {
            $(this).hide();
        });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't appear to do anything :-(

Comment: You can put some html to see the structure of "comment-wrapper" and "comment-modbox"

Comment: Or just use `$(this).find(....)` which is what `$(...., this)` is doing internally.