# Get each selector of a multi selector jQuery object as a string

Tags: jquery, string, selector

If I pass a number of selectors to jQuery, how can I differentiate the selector of each of those selectors as separate strings? For example:

```
$('#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c').each(function(){
    console.log( $(this).selector ); // logs an empty string
});
```

Comment: Look like you actually wanted to put a class on each element and select by class. Making an id for everything isn't right.

Comment: Are you asking how you can extract the ID of a selector? Just use `$(this).attr("id")` for that.

Comment: `var j = $('#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c');` and then `j.selector`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708901/jquery-multiple-selectors-with-this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.each($('#selector-a, #selector-b, #selector-c').selector.split(','),
       function(index, value) {
           console.log(value);
       }
);
```