# Jquery - Using $(this) with multiple selectors?

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Jquery multiple selectors with this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708901/jquery-multiple-selectors-with-this)

Is it possible to use multiple selectors with $(this)? I tried:

```
$('#helper').click(function() {
$(this + " #divname").html());
});
```

But it never works. I just want to make sure its selecting the div within the div that was clicked on.

Comment: Btw IDs are supposed to be unique, so if you have multiple elements with the ID `divname`, then you are doing something wrong.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. What is the statement in the function supposed to achieve? Also, why would you need $(this) in this case? You already know "helper" was clicked. Finally, you can always use $(this).children("#divname") or .find() - depending on your DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are trying to look for a child of `this` you can do it like

```
$('#helper').click(function() {
$(" #divname",this ).html());
});
```